# From recurrence relation to solution

Tags: convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

I have some hard time solving some of the following problems:

Consider the    recurrence relation $x_n=2(x_{n-1}+x_{n-2})$

1) Show that the general solution   is  $z_n=\alpha(1+\sqrt3)^n+\beta (1-\sqrt3)^n$ and  determine   whether the difference  equation    is  stable.

2) Show that starting values $x_1=1$ and $x_2=(1-\sqrt3)$ corresponds  to  the solution with $\alpha =0$ and    $\beta=(1-\sqrt3)^{-1}$

3) For  which   values  of  $\alpha, \beta$ ∈ ℝ does the general solution    converge?   Determine   the order   of  the
rate    of  convergence for these   values.

I don't know how to find the solution to the recurrence relation, the literature we have been given from out teacher only about convergent sequences (linear convergence, superlinear convergence, quadratic convergence) so i dont know how the heck they went from  $x_n=2(x_{n-1}+x_{n-2})$ to $z_n=\alpha(1+\sqrt3)^n+\beta (1-\sqrt3)^n$. So I need someone who can push me in the right direction step by step.

Comment: Well, you are not asked to solve it, just to confirm that the proposed solution is correct.  That is much easier...just show that $z_n$ satisfies the correct recursion.

Comment: So when I try to solve the recurrence relation $x_n=2(x_{n-1}+x_{n-2})$ I need to solve $x_n-2(x_{n-1}+x_{n-2})$ or what??

Comment: Once again you are not asked to solve the recurrence...just to confirm that the proposed solution does satisfy the recurrence.

Comment: If you want to learn how to solve such things, you might start [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Characteristic_polynomial).  But, again, the present question does not require this.

Comment: How do I show that the proposed solution satisfies the correct recursion? I want so solve it by myself but I don't know where to go from here

Comment: As a hint to checking that $z_n$ works:  convince yourself that it suffices to check for each of $(1\pm \sqrt 3)^n$ separately.  It should be very easy for you to show that, say, $a_n=(1+\sqrt 3)^n$ satisfies the recursion.

Comment: So I need to check: $(1+\sqrt3)^n = 2((1+\sqrt3)^{n-1}+(1+\sqrt3)^{n-2})$ and the for $(1-\sqrt3)^n$ is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  And you need to explain why this solves the general case (with $\alpha, \beta$).

Comment: I am little bit confused about $\alpha$ and $\beta$ because in my litterature they do not mention $\alpha, \beta$ what do they represent?

Comment: Look at what you wrote for $z_n$.   $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants appearing in your formula.

Comment: how do I determine wheter the difference equation is stable?

Comment: Well, do you know what "stable" means in this context?